# PHP::PDO opening/closing connections multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Lets say I've got a function that makes calls to PHP::PDO, the function opens a connection, runs the MySQL, closes the connection, returns some data.

I haven't seen any serious problems with this, but is there any reason why this is a bad practice? What are the risks of doing this?

Comment: You mean create a new instance of a `PDO` object each time the function is called? If so; any particular reason you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No risks that I'm aware of, but there is network lag for establishing connections. It will likely work fine now when you are just connecting to `localhost`, but your application will probably have scaling issues if you're establishing multiple connections for each HTTP request and you ever want to move to a secondary database server for whatever reason.

A PHP page is inherently single-threaded, so unless you are starting up multiple threads yourself then there's no (extra) concurrency issues. It's still a good idea to use InnoDB and SQL transactions to help prevent concurrency issues across multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair amount of overhead involved with opening and closing the connection multiple times. It isn't really a that big a deal until it becomes a performance problem.  If it does become a problem, you will want to modify it to keep the connection open for the duration of the script and reuse the same connection for multiple database transactions. That's a fairly common practice.

If you do not have a fixed (and small) number of database transactions per script, I would recommend against connecting and tearing down the connection on each action.  Instead open it once and hold the connection until the script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not have more queries to run, I do not see this as an issue.

Comment: My concern is that I might be doing something funky with the SQL server in the event of `n` queries. Where `n` is a number I don't know the value of.